# Get the value of a BehaviorSubject

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I am attempting to get the values of a BehaviorSubject. The values are returned but how to i utilized them to use them in a return true/false statement.

```
BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
closed:false
hasError:false
isStopped:false
observers:[Subscriber]
thrownError:null
value:(...)
_isScalar:false
_value:Array(3)
0:"name@gmail.com"
1:"Bob Smith"
2:{adminUser: false, basicUser: true} length:3
__proto__:Array(0)
__proto__:Subject
```

My Behavior Subject has the following being sent to it. Why am i getting null at the start.

```
user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
```

// The behavior-roles of the user.

```
 this.afAuth.authState
                .switchMap(auth => {
                if (auth) {
                    /// signed in
                    const authData = this.db.list<User>('users/' + auth.uid).valueChanges();
                    console.log(authData);
                    return this.db.list<User>('users/' + auth.uid).valueChanges();
                } else {
                    /// not signed in
                    return Observable.of(null);
                }
                })
                // .subscribe(console.log); // check the subscription
                .subscribe((userData) => {
                console.log(userData);
                this.user.next(userData);
                // this.user.next(user);
                // console.log(this.user.next(userData));
                });
            }
```

The results i am having issues with:

```
Check Value false authguard.service.ts:39 
Route was False authguard.service.ts:26 
Check Value true
```

I run console.log and the value shows up null first therefore has a false response. Then it runs again and becomes true. This all happens after running the page initially. I need for my check value to be true on load.

Comment: .value() should do it

Answer (score 14):

You should just be able to call the name of the BehaviorSubject with the .getValue()
so something like:

```
let x = new BehaviorSubject<any>;
...
x.getValue()
```

Comment: So when i try to get the value i receive null. I have read before to do .getValue(), but always receive null. If i take the BehaviorSubject and subscribe to it, then i will get null and then the values. Why am i getting null first? user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null); // The behavior-roles of the user.

Comment: @Kevin Summersill it's Because you have initialized it to null and BehaviourSubject will always return the initial value or the current value on Subscription

Comment: Is there way to only get the current value and not the initial value. I have an angular navigation using route guards, when i click on the nav to go to the page it loads up initial first instead of the current value.

Comment: I used the skip() rxjs operator

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. I always get my initial value (which is null) and never the emitted values. `skip()`-method dosen't help me but the `skipWhile()`-method was the trick.

```js
behaviorSubject.pipe(
   skipWhile(value => !value), // skip null values
   take(1)) // in my case, I need the value only once
   .subscribe(value => doYourWork());
```

---

### Edit

If it possible, then it´s the best solution to switch to a `ReplaySubject` of size 1. You need no `.skip()` or `.skipeWhile()` anymore.
Here is an example.

```
// replaySubjects have no initial value
let subject = new ReplaySubject<YourType>(1); 


subject.pipe(take(1)).
    // no null-values anymore!
    .subscribe(value => doYourStuff());

// subscribers dont get any value until a next()-call
subject.next(youValue);

// and you can hide some methods, when you declare it as observable or subject
// hide replaySubject specific informations
let publicSubject: Subject<YourType> = subject;
// hide subject informations (like .next())
let publicSubject2: Observable<YourType> = subject;
```

Comment: Can you answer for this? sixtwo49843nine

Comment: Did you mean me?

Comment: Check the question number

Comment: Oh god. Can you just copy the link to the question next time? :D

Answer (score 0):

I have officially answered my question. May not be the right way but it sure did work.

The **BehaviorSubject** from **rxjs** produces both the *initial and current value*
at that particular steam of time. Now if you want to **bypass** the **initial value** (which in my case was *null*) then before you subscribe to it, make sure to use the **[skip operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/skip.html)**.

Which I used in this case to skip the first value skip(1).

```
// RxJS v6+
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { skip } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit every 1s
const source = interval(1000);
//skip the first 5 emitted values
const example = source.pipe(skip(5));
//output: 5...6...7...8........
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```