# async pipe not working correctly with BehaviorSubject piped with DelayWhen

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a very strange behavior while working with Angular 9 and Rxjs Observables. I have a component and a service. The service has a public `$messages` Behavior subject, that I subscribe to in the component.

My problem is whenever I execute the `next` function on the behavior subject in the chat service, the `async` operator in the html seems to ignore all the operators in the pipe in the component, including the `DelayWhen` operator. Although the `map` operator follows the right behahvior, and executes after seconds.

What might be the cause of this behavior and how to fix it?

**Chat Service**

```
export class ChatService {
    messages: Message[];
    messages$: BehaviorSubject<Message[]>;

    constructor(){

            this.messages = [
                {
                    message: 'Hi How can I help you today?',
                    created_at: '2020-04-11 17:58:27',
                    agent_id: '1'
                  },
                  {
                    message: 'Whats the pricing model?',
                    created_at: '2020-04-11 13:58:27',
                    visitor_id: '043-reer-reer-reer-re-er'
                  }  
            ];

            this.messages$ = new BehaviorSubject<Message[]>(this.messages);

            this.cn.on("messageReceived", (message:Message) => {

                this.apiService.getMessage(message.id).subscribe(
                    res => {
                        this.messages.push(res.model);
                        this.flush_to_storage();  
                        this.messages$.next(this.messages); <-- I call the next here
                       ....
    }
```

**Component**

```
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

    messages$: Observable<Message[]> ;
    show_typing_indicator: boolean = false;

    ...

    ngOninit(){

        this.messages$ = this.chatService.messages$.pipe( 
            delayWhen( ms => { /* This is ignore altogether by the async in the html component */
                let m = ms[ms.length - 1];
                if (m.is_bot) {
                    this.show_typing_indicator = true;
                    setTimeout( () => this.show_typing_indicator = false, 3000 );
                    return interval(3000);
                }
                else return of(undefined);
            }),
            map( ms => {console.log(ms); return ms})
        );

}
```

**Component Html**

```
                    <div class="cl-message-block" *ngFor="let m of (messages$ | async)" [@fadeIn] [class.sent]="!m.agent_id">


                        <div class="cl-message" [ngClass]="{ 'cl-received': (m.agent_id), 'cl-sent': (!m.agent_id) }">
                            {{ m.message}}
                            <span>{{ m.created_at | messageTime }}</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <charla-typing-indicator *ngIf="show_typing_indicator"></charla-typing-indicator>
```

Comment: may be this link help https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5318

Comment: _"Although the map operator follows the right behahvior, and executes after seconds"_ do you mean that you see the messages printed on the console by `map( ms => {console.log(ms); return ms})`?

Comment: yes but after 3 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated ur [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-tqtcy9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchat.service.ts) and I think it's working fine now

U have multiple issues with it

1-**Saving state in this.messages in ChatService is bad idea**
bcs u are using **BehaviorSubject** then use **BehaviorSubject.value**, this.Messages$.value has ur last Message[].

2- **Inplace editing** is not good thing maybe bcs of it and [changeDetectionStratgy.onpush](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy#OnPush) u are having issue

```
this.messages.push(res.model);
this.messages$.next(this.messages);
```

instead create a new array to add new message

```
 let newMessages = [...this.messages$.value, newMessage ]
 this.messages$.next(newMessages);
```

//miner one

3-when using WhenDelay in else condition use **interval(0)** instead of of(undefine) bcs first one make sense if u think about it

```
if (m.is_bot) {
                  // other code
                    return interval(3000);
                }
                else {
                  return interval(0);
                }
```

Comment: great works now, thanks for putting the time to help out and the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

BehaviourSubjects have an initial value, we don't see where you set it in your code, but typically that first value is initialised to null or undefined.  You aren't doing any null checks in your delayWhen body.  Wrap that in a

```
if (ms) {
}
```

and see if that changes your output.

You are initialising messages$ somewhere... aren't you?

```
messages$ = new BehaviorSubject<Message[]>(null);
```

The real lesson here is to always add error handling on your subscription so the error from your asynchronous source will be reported to you and you will instantly understand what the problem is.

e.g.

```
....subscribe({
  next: (result) => {
    if (result) {
      // Do the work
    }
  }
  error: (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

or a catchError if you are subscribing in your template

```
....pipe(
  // Assorted RxJS operators go here

  // either this:
  catchError((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    return throwError(err);  // re-throw it if you might want to also see the error downstream
  }

  // or this:
  catchError((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    return of<MyType>(undefined);  // return a clean (typed) observable if you don't want the error downstream
  }
});
```

Comment: i added the initialization code to the question, i already initialize it with an array so don't think this is the problem

Comment: Looks good.  So I agree with you that the null check is probably not the problem.  But I would recommend some simple error handling, even if it is just for testing/figuring out what is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps when you use a `ReplaySubject` instead of a `BehaviorSubject`.
`ReplaySubjects` have no intial values and when you not have a requirement for initial values (or in other words: default values), then you should use them.

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57214877/6537157 for more details.

Answer (score -1):

## chat service

```
messages = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
messagesListner = this.messages.asObservable();

constructor() {
    this.cn.on("messageReceived", (message: Message) => {

        this.apiService.getMessage(message.id).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.messages.push(res.model);
                this.flush_to_storage();
                this.messages.next(this.messages); <--I call the next here
                   ....
}
```

## component

```
import { ChartService } from '';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

constructor(
    private chatService: ChartService
) {}
messageSubscription: Subscription;
ngOninit(){

    this.messageSubscription = this.messagesListner.messages.pipe( 
        delayWhen( ms => { /* This is ignore altogether by the async in the html component */
            let m = ms[ms.length - 1];
            if (m.is_bot) {
                this.show_typing_indicator = true;
                setTimeout( () => this.show_typing_indicator = false, 3000 );
                return interval(3000);
            }
            else return of(undefined);
        }),
        map( ms => {console.log(ms); return ms})
    );

}
```

Comment: and where the messages listener is used ?

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam  pls check now