# Logout function doesnt work when called from app.component.ts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a Logout() function in my authentication Service like this:

```
export class AuthService {

isAuthenticated = new BehaviorSubject(false);

constructor(private router: Router) { }

  Logout()
  {
    console.log('Logout')
    if(this.isAuthenticated.value === true)
      {this.isAuthenticated.next(false);}
    this.router.navigateByUrl('login')
  }
}
```

that gets called from my side menu where it works just fine.

However if I call it from my app.component.ts like this:

```
constructor(private auth: AuthService)
  {this.auth.isAuthenticated.subscribe((x)=>{
    if(this.auth.isAuthenticated.value === false)
    {
      this.auth.Logout();
    }
  })}
```

the function gets called (console.log('logout') works) but I don't get Routed

To test the function I made a Button on my HomePage that sets isAuthenticated to false.

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  Test()
  {
    this.auth.isAuthenticated.next(false);
  }

}
```

Logout gets called but doesn't work 
-> 'Logout' gets logged in Console but doesn't Route

-> changing the button to call the Logout() function directly works just fine

```
  Test()
  {
    this.auth.Logout();
  }
```

Calling the **same Logout** function from the side menu on the **same Page** just works
fine

I don't get any Error Messages.

What is the reason for the function not working when called from app.component and how can I make it work?

Thanks in advance for any Help.

PS: Iam 100% certain that

1. The Logout function is called.
2. That the route call is **not in the if loop**

Bonus Info:
isAuthenticated is supposed to be false on Logout(). The if loop checking for a true isAuthenticate and setting it to false is just for security

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-arlwgz?file=README.md) (is stuck in starting dev server for me however all the code is there)

Comment: I don't immedately see a reason why the routing wouldn't work, could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Can you tell me what info you would need because there isn't much more in the app, because I built it just for testing this. Its just a Loginpage, a Homepage, a authentication service, a guard(only guards homepgae),  and the  basic Ionic app structure.

Comment: Pardon, the link does describe what a MRE is, but it can be a little much to read... Basically you want to create a project on an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) and reproduce your problem over there so people can take a look at what's going on and also see the code. It's also debuggable as opposed to only having the code here :-)

Comment: @Greencoms Why are you not using authGuard for this kind of scenario? AuthGuard is specially designed for such an schenario where authentication needs to be checked

Comment: @Greencoms Have you tried to put same block into ngOnInit() hook instead of in constructor() block?

Comment: Put your `console.log('Logout')` in the `if` statement you will see that it does not run. As you are subscribing in the constructor, the first value emitted by `isAuthenticated ` is `false`. Because BehaviourSubject emits the initial value, thats why it runs the logout function, but it does not pass the if condition, so the routing does not work. I believe this should be `this.auth.isAuthenticated.value === true` in your constructor subscription then the routing will work.

Comment: @JayPatel when I put it in ngOnit it has the same effect

Comment: @hawks im not stupid I tested for that it before I asked the question. The logout function is run on change of the behavior subjects value, which fires on initialization but that doesn't matter because  your already on the login page. I want to run Logout if you are **NOT AUTHENTICATED** not if you are so changing my if statement would only be contra productive especially in this test app. If you would have read the question you would see that to test the Logout by setting the BehaviorSubject to false, so tell me why would I want to Logout on a true value?

Comment: I did not say you are stupid, but.... If you want to run your Logout function if you are *NOT AUTHENTICATED* THEN CHECK YOUR `if(this.isAuthenticated.value === true)
      {this.isAuthenticated.next(false);}
    this.router.navigateByUrl('login')
  }`  this will not run, I assume the isAuthenticated is set to false somewhere else. This condition will not run, coz isAuthenticated is false. Yes, changing the if true does not make sense, I got it wrong there.

Comment: @hawks In my app I have console.log() **everywhere** even in the If loop of the call and in the logout function. It all runs how its supposed to just the route doesn't work. The if loop before the router call is just to make sure that on Logout the isAuthenticated is false no matter what. And if you look closely you will notice that the route call is **after** not **in** the if loop.

Comment: @JayPatel Tell me if I am wrong but can Guards only hinder you from Loading a Page, not send you back to the Login Page as soon as your Auth state changes.

Comment: Maybe use `.getValue()` instead of `.value`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277874/get-the-value-of-a-behaviorsubject#answers-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login appears to be subscribed to isAuthenticated and because according to your Stackblitz you dont check for the state of isAuthenticated and just route to your Homepage on change. So you

- change isAuthenticated to false
- get Routed to your Loginpage
- The Login gets the change and Routes you back to your Homepage

Answer (score 0):

I think it is routing related issue and please check where you define the route.

Comment: Its not as I mentioned in the Question calling the same Function -> also calling the same Route works just not from app.component.ts

Comment: are you using  nested routes like account/login?

Comment: Yes I do but that is not the Problem

Comment: ok then you have to  route like module/component and it should work for you.

Comment: As I said the route works and I use navigate by Route -> /login not /component/login

Comment: no I was  just want to ask you that  this problem with ```this.router.navigateByUrl('login')``` this piece of code please verify this.