# Angular Logout Route not called

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a LogoutFunction. However, it is not dispatched to my API(spring Boot).
Login works fine, though.
I want to pass an ID to API and get a success boolean back.

The Method is definitely called. Console logs until the http POST:

Postman also makes it to the API, where the corresponding function is called to and output is written to terminal.

TypeScript:

```
logout(): Observable<LogoutResponse> {
        const logoutMessage: LogoutMessage = new LogoutMessage();
        const Id= this.getIdFromLocalStorage();
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

        if (Id!== null && accessToken && accessToken !== '') {
            logoutMessage.Id= Id!;
        }

        console.log(logoutMessage);
        console.log(this.apiUrl + 'auth/logout');
        return this.http
            .post<LogoutResponse>(this.apiUrl + 'auth/logout', logoutMessage, { responseType: 'json' })
            .pipe(
                tap((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.success) {
                        this.onLogoutSuccessful();
                    }
                })
            );
    }

<div class="logout" *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)">
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="authService.logout()">
        Abmelden
</button>
</div>
```

LogoutMessage looks fine.Logout-Button is in app.component.html. But function in my auth.service.ts is called, as i can prove with the logs above.

Heres a similar issue, but not resolved and applicable to my case.
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75081733/logout-function-doesnt-work-when-called-from-app-component-ts)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please add the code showing how you call the logout. And is the response log visible?

Comment: I edited the code fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pes have said, you have to subscribe to Logout in order to call it properly. Implement a function within your component with logout button and subscribe to it within the function:

```typescript
logout(): void {
  this.authService.logout().subscribe({
    next: response => { /* handle response */ },
    error: error => { /* handle error */ }
  })
}
```

Call it like that then:

```html
<div class="logout" *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)">
  <button mat-raised-button color="warn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="logout()">
    Abmelden
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not subscribing to `logout()` therefore the http request is not executed. You must subscribe to `HttpClient` observables to become "hot".